# Ptcl EVO not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: internet, ruby, mobile-broadband, zte

I live in Islamabad, Pakistan and when I am outdoor, I use Ptcl EVO with my windows 7 and it works fine, but now when I used it with Ubuntu 14.04, it worked fine initially but after sometime it stopped working (Its light is blinking, and is properly connecting, but the internet is not working).
Today I updated and upgraded Ubuntu, installed some software (sublime, chrome, Vim), installed Node, Ruby and Ruby on Rails etc, so I don't know if the problem occurred because of something installed today or what?

Following is the device ID (got from console using lsusb)

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 19d2:fff1 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

Thank You! :)

Edit: I reinstalled Ubuntu and looked for all the changes, the 3g mobile broadband usb stopped working sharply after the libindicator and libappindicator were installed (automatically by ubuntu).
Here is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with PTCL EVO 3g on Ubuntu 15.04. This is how I solved it.

1. Right-click on the network icon on the tray.
2. Go to Edit Connections.
3. Select PTCL EVO Connection in the list.
4. Click on Edit.
5. Click on tab PPP settings.
6. Deselect Allow BSD data compression, Allow deflate data compression, Use TCP Header Compression.
7. Restart ubuntu just to be on the safe side.
8. Activate your broadband connection.

I stumbled upon the solution by observing a number of malformed packet headers in my Wireshark dump. I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm on vacations right now, I'll check it once I'm back. Thank You for the answer.