# Configure Wireshark for PPPoE connection

Tags: networking, pppoe, wireshark

Wireshark is not displaying my PPPoE connection in its interface list.
Official [wireshark website](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/PPP#Linux) says PPP connections can be captured by configuring the ppp daemon and I've no idea how to do the same.

My Ubuntu version : 14.04.3

Wireshark version : 1.10.6 (from Ubuntu Software Center)

My Network Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Wireshark empty interface list:
[image]

I've even tried a solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634186/ptcl-evo-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/663207#663207) but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit Wireshark, run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common`, and then start up Wireshark again.

Wireshark lists *no* interfaces, which means the problem may have nothing to do with PPPoE, and may have to do with Wireshark (or, rather, the dumpcap program it runs to do capturing) not having enough privileges to capture traffic.  Running Wireshark as root is [An Extremely Bad Idea](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.packaging;h=6446fe1fdafb16849b1d78162ac3502d6a6247e1;hb=HEAD); the right way to give "minimum privileges" to Wireshark on Debian and on Debian derivatives such as Ubuntu is with the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common` command.

What you read on the official Wireshark website is talking about capturing PPP *control* traffic; you can capture *data*, such as IP traffic, on a PPP device, with tcpdump/Wireshark/etc..  I'm not sure the PPP daemon is even *involved* with PPPoE, so that may not apply.

Comment: Thanks, but after using your command I got some access denied error in wireshark saying "couldn't run /usr/bin/dumpcap"  Hence I used the following commands from [here](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/28993/ubuntu-install/28996) which solved my problem.

"sudo addgroup -system wireshark" 
"sudo chown root:wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap" 
"sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/dumpcap"
"sudo usermod -a -G wireshark YOUR_USER_NAME"

Comment: If `sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common` doesn't work, that sounds like a bug in the Ubuntu package; report it to the Ubuntu maintainers.